# Density of component of absolutely continuous random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

From *Probability* by Alan F. Karr, **Proposition 2.29** states

*If $X = (X_1,\ldots, X_d)$ is absolutely continuous, then for each $i$, $X_i$ is absolutely continuous and*
$$
f_{X_{i}}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{i-1}, x, y_{i+1}, \ldots, y_{d}\right)
\; d y_{1} \cdots d y_{i-1} d y_{i+1} \cdots d y_{d}
$$

***Proof.***
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left\{X_{i} \leq t\right\}=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{t} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{d}\right) d y_{1} \cdots d y_{d} \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{t}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{i-1}, x, y_{i+1}, \ldots, y_{d}\right) d y_{1} \cdots d y_{i-1} d y_{i+1} \cdots d y_{d}\right] d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $f_{X_i}(x)$ is the integrand, i.e
$$
f_{X_i}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{i-1}, x, y_{i+1}, \ldots, y_{d}\right) d y_{1} \cdots d y_{i-1} d y_{i+1} \cdots d y_{d}
$$
as required.

---

This proof requires that the order of integration is changed in the joint CDF. The integral corresponding to $x$ is taken out to the front. Why is this allowed, and under what conditions can we do this in general? Thanks.

Comment: Since $X$ is an absolutely continuous random variable, the density $f_X$ is non-negative and any integral of it over a measurable volume is bounded above by $1$, so yes, you can change the order of integration

Comment: By Tonelli's Theorem you can always interchange the order of integration when the integrand is a non-negative measurable function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! Haven't encountered Tonelli's Theorem yet, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Henry You only need one of  the two conditions: non-negativity, integrability. You don't need both.